# Job completes successfully and logs the errors to a text file

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I am using Ola's scripts for our database backups, I am trying to come up with a way to be notified if any of the database backup fails. Job completes successfully and logs the errors to text file, Can we get a  notification\alert that it found errors.

Answer (score 3):

Create a notification for the Job failure. The below email will help you with the steps:

Step 1 : Configure database mail and do a test if thats working fine.

Step 2 : Change Agent properties 
         Under Mail session, select the option to Enable mail profile. Ensure the correct Mail profile is selected.

Step 3 : Create Operator.
         Under the SQL Server Agent, right-click Operators and select New Operator and configure accordingly.

Step 4 : Under the job properties for the backup, go to Notification tab and select email when the job fails:

[image]

Step 4 :

[Notification for job failure](https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/)

Comment: Sure,will do that

Comment: There's also a stored procedure out there called: spDBA_job_notification.  If you install that, say in master, then you could save yourself some extra steps after a job failure by configuring your job steps 'On Failure' to run this procedure as the final step in your job.  The failure email notification will have what you are capturing in your log.

Comment: I have already enabled email Notification. I'm using Ola hallengren backup script, problem is i have a full backup job which executes successfully but when i checked the logs one of the database backup got failed due to not enough free space. I did not received any alert saying backup got failed for a particular DB.